# what are Sesam docker tags i can chose from for a node?

Tags: sesam

I would like to know my options regarding the Sesam docker tags to subscribe to for my node and any limitations for a given choice.
Can someone explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Weekly-Prod is recommended, only reason to use any other would be if you need a hotfix or a really fresh feature. If Sesam hosts you you can ask support change it for you. I would highly recommend keeping it default.

```
Weekly-Prod    Night to monday + 7days
Weekly         Night to monday
Nightly        Night to current day
Latest         Whenever a build has completed it will install and restart the node
```